# Recover objective function in an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, reference-request

Is it possible to recover the objective function of an optimization problem, given the value function and the constraint?

Specifically, consider two real-valued functions, $f : [a_0, a_1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : [b_0, b_1] \to \mathbb{R}$, and the following maximization problem:

$$ \underset{x \in [a_0, a_1],\\ y \in [b_0, b_1]}{\text{maximize}} \quad f(x) g(y) \qquad \text{subject to} \quad x y = k.$$
Here $k\in[a_0b_0,a_1b_1]$ is the parameter of this problem. Let $V(k)$ be the value function.

Suppose that we know the functions $V$ and $f$. Is it possible to **recover** the function $g$?

Is there any reference for this type of questions?

Comment: What's the motivation for this question? Where does this come from?

Comment: The motivation is that people might make decisions based on the value of some optimization problem. In some cases, the value function may be observed but the objective function is private or only partially known. I am dealing with such a problem which can be reduced to the one in this post.

Comment: Please include such information in the question itself